# i am getting this error when i typing this command

Tags: shell, find, dumpsys

C:\Users\hp>adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"
'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\hp>adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"
'find' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: From the error message, I conclude that you do not run this as POSIX shell script. Please tag your question with the shell you are using (most likely _powershell_  or _cmd_). Also, in your question please don't write everything (code and explanation) in the same line; it makes it hard to read, as you probably can see by your self.

Answer (score 0):

In windows find don't exist, you need to put findstr or you can do adb shell after this use grep like this.
adb shell dumpsys window displays| findstr "mCurrentFocus"

adb shell
dumpsys window displays| grep "mCurrentFocus"